# How to I can see the object rotation value being changed during the simulation?

Tags: transforms, rigid-body-simulation

The image below by example, in the simulation the "Axis" object was being rotated by a motor ridigbody constraint, I want see the rotation value changed during the simulation, but when I see the "Transform Menu" (opened right in the image below) I can't see the value of the rotation being changed.

[image]

So, How to I can see the object rotation value being changed during the simulation?